# Functions within functions

Tags: functions

Am I on the right track? I am learning about relations and functions. Does the domain restriction make it so I have to have my answer between 0 and 17?

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{17x-x^2}$ and $g(x) = 3x+4$, defined over a domain of $[0,17]$. Determine $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$.

$(f(g(x)) =$

$= \sqrt{17(3x+4)-(3x+4)^2}$

$= \sqrt{(51x+68)-(9x^2+16)}$

$= \sqrt{51x+68-9x^2-16)}$

$= \sqrt{9x^2-27x-52}$

Answer (score 2):

> $= \sqrt{17(3x+4)-(3x+4)^2}$
>
> $= \sqrt{(51x+68)-(9x^2\color{blue}{+24x}+16)}$

You forgot to write the term $\color{blue}{24x}$ from $(a+b)^2=a^2\color{blue}{+2ab}+b^2$

> $= \sqrt{51x+68-9x^2-16\color{blue}{-24x}}$
>
> $= \sqrt{\color{red}{9x^2-27x-52}}$

What happens to the signs here?
$$51x+68-9x^2-16-24x=-9x^2+27x+52 \ne \color{red}{9x^2-27x-52}$$

Comment: I wanted to have the $x^2$ term positive so I multipied by negative 1.

Comment: But you're not allowed to do that; you're changing the function... Note that, for example, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ are different functions!